# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute, merging csv

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have multiple`.csv` files into a folder and they have the same structure. 
First two columns contain two values `k1` and `k2` the third column contain a numerical value.
I want to iterate on these files and merge them into a new `csv`, where I will have the first two columns for `K1` and `K2` and then `n` columns, one for each of the `n` files.
This is my solution:

```
import glob
import csv
import os

def get_data(filename):
    '''function to read the data form the input csv file to use in the analysis'''
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)                      
        result = {tuple(row[:2]): row[2] for row in reader}
        return result   

path='mypath' 
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv')):

    print ("Current File Being Processed is:  " + infile) 
    #use split to seperate the path and name of the file
    (PATH, FILENAME) = os.path.split(infile)
    all_data=[]
    #adds the data from the csv file to a blank list so it can be operated on
    all_data.extend(get_data(infile))

result = {}

for dic in all_data:
    for key in (dic.viewkeys() | result.keys()):
        if key in dic: result.setdefault(key, []).append(dic[key])
        else: result.setdefault(key, []).append(0)


with open('mypath', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in result:
            writer.writerow(data)
```

but it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\p.py", line 26, in <module>
    for key in (dic.viewkeys() | result.keys()):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'viewkeys'
```

Comment: are you using jupyter?

Comment: No, I'm working on Python IDLE

Answer (score 1):

```
    result = {tuple(row[:2]): row[2] for row in reader}
```

You are storing key as tuple(key) and hence iterating over it throwing error for you.

Comment: he is creating a dict with tuples as keys and putting that dict into a list, therfore he has something like [{(.....):[.....]}]. Therfore his dic variable in the loop should actually point to a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks. What could be a possible alternative solution?

Comment: @FlorianH no, they are doing `all_data.extend(get_data(infile))` which iterates over the tuples in the dict returned by `get_data`, adding them to the list, so it will be a list of tuples.

Comment: @ds1993 perhaps you meant `all_data.append(get_data(infile))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga maybe the difference between append and extend is not clear to me. I read that if I have x = [1, 2, 3] and I use x.append([4, 5]) it should return something like [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]], while extend should return something like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], then I thought extend was the right solution for me.

Comment: Anyway, I replaced extend with append, but I have still the same error.

Comment: @ds1993 you wouldn't be getting the exact same error. Anyway, how do you expect `x = [1,2,3]; x.extend({'a':1, 'b':2})` to work? Have you actually tried to see?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, you're right and the error is not exactly the same, but it is:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\p.py", line 25, in <module>
    for key in (dic.viewkeys() | result.keys()):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'viewkeys' `